# How to add date to stderr (not filename but inside log file)?

Tags: linux, command

I have a `crontab` entry:
`00 10 * * * test.sh>>output_log 2>>error_log`

But I want to also include date into `output_log` and `error_log` in the beginning line of each day.

How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```bsh
{ echo `date` && . test.sh; }>>output_log 2>>error_log
```

but it just includes date only in output_log because `echo date` is not considered as `stderr` so that is not included in `2`.

I want something like this psuedo code:

```bsh
{ echo `date` && . test.sh }>>output_log { echo `date` plus 2's content } >>error_log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simply:

```
0 10 * * * { date; date >&2; test.sh; } >> output_log 2>> error_log
```

It might also be interesting to use the `ts` utility from Moreutils, which will prepend a timestamp to every line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 10 * * * test.sh > >(ts >> output_log) 2> >(ts >> error_log)
```

(Note the use of `/bin/bash`, as the most basic POSIX `/bin/sh` does not support the `>()` redirection construct.)

Answer (score 3):

I think if you change your `crontab` line as follows, you will get what you want - or at least what I **think** you want. If it doesn't do as you wish, leave a comment. You may also wish to edit your question to clarify your objective.

#### Prototype `crontab` entry for test/eval:

```
* * * * * { cat hellofile_NOFILE.txt ; echo $(date) | tee -a error_log; } >> /home/pi/output_log 2>>/home/pi/error_log
```

I don't have your `test.sh` script, so I used `cat file` instead. To create an error in `cat`, I simply pointed to a non-existent file - something to send some output to `stderr` to verify it goes into `error_log`.

You wanted a date-time stamp in both `error_log` and `output_log`. Piping `date` to `tee -a error_log` should put a timestamp in the error log.

I replaced `&&` with `;` because I think you wanted a date-time stamp even if `cat` (or in your case `test.sh`) fails to execute.

I know this doesn't match exactly with your question. I've proposed it in this way so that you can test the logic. If the logic is correct, I think it "translates" to your situation as follows:

#### Revised `crontab` entry:

```
00 10 * * * { test.sh ; echo $(date) | tee -a error_log; } >> output_log 2>> error_log
```